# How to display draw rectangle from OpenCV.MatchTemplate

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to find an image within a screenshot and draw a rectangle around it. What I don't understand it how to interpret my `result` matrix to identify the area containing the image.

The below code will draw a rectangle, but it's not really in the right place and I don't know if that's because I'm not using my `result` correctly or something else.

```
using (Mat templateImage = CvInvoke.Imread("\\top_1.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.AnyColor))
using (Mat inputImage = CvInvoke.Imread(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\currentScreen.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.AnyColor))
{
    Mat result = new Mat();
    CvInvoke.MatchTemplate(inputImage, templateImage, result, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.SqdiffNormed);

    result.MinMax(out double[] minVal, out double[] maxVal, out Point[] minLoc, out Point[] maxLoc);

    int x = minLoc[0].X;
    int y = minLoc[0].Y;
    int w = maxLoc[0].X - minLoc[0].X;
    int h = maxLoc[0].Y - minLoc[0].Y;

    Form f = new Form
    {
        BackColor = Color.Red,
        //TransparencyKey = Color.Red,
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
        TopMost = true,
        Location = new Point(x, y),
        Size = new Size(w, h)
    };

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my error after reading and re-reading the documentation a few times. I ended up not using this as I found a much simpler and more reliable method for my use case, but for the benefit of others:

The function `MinMax()` gives you both minimum and maximum because which one you use depends on the matching type used. For example `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.SqdiffNormed` returns results where the min is the greatest match.

The location returned in minLoc is just the top left co-ordinate of the `templateImage` and so it matches on the same size area as `templateImage` meaning I just had to do:

```
int x = minLoc[0].X;
int y = minLoc[0].Y;
int w = maxLoc[0].X + templateImage.Width;
int h = maxLoc[0].Y + templateImage.Height;
```

I got caught out because I didn't assume the `templateImage` found within `inputImage` had be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is the position of the form, you must set the StarPosition to Manual

```
            Form f = new Form
            {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                BackColor = Color.Red,
                //TransparencyKey = Color.Red,
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
                TopMost = true,
                Location = new Point(x, y),
                Size = new Size(w, h)
            };
```

[This is the screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGSqG.png)

[This is the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeIB3.png)

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UvRI.png)

[This is with out StartPosition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reBwq.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue with the form I'm using so much as the location I'm inputting. I don't think StartPosition matters here.

Comment: Could you try it by drawing the rectangle directly on the image and not with a form on the screen?

Comment: I figured it out in the end (I was correct, it wasn't anything to do with `Form f`, but thanks for your help anyway. See my answer if interested.